# cocos2d-x screen flicker on Android

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I got screen flicker when developing with cocos2d-x 3.0alpha1.

I designed the resources on 480x800 resolution.

Then I try on both my android phone ( HTC One V ) and tablet. It works fine on my phone which is 480x800 without scaling. But it flickers on my Android tablet which has 600x1024 reesolution ( HTC Flyer ).

This is the video of how the flicker going on
http://youtu.be/f_-TilhW3ns

I've tried

Director::getInstance()->setDepthTest(false);
Director::getInstance()->setProjection(Director::Projection::_2D);

with no success.

Has anybody encounter this before and maybe fixed it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the following code in your AppDelegate.cpp in your AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() methode :

```
 glview->setDesignResolutionSize(720,1280,ResolutionPolicy::SHOW_ALL);
```

Worked for me. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue I problem was that I was using too big sprite sheets, and also use CCParticleBatchNodes you you are using particles.